# Merging android manifest files, conflicting filter

Tags: android, merge, manifest

I'm trying to combine android manifest files from 2 plugins in Unity, but there are two activities with the same intent-filter and I can only get 1 or the other to work at the same time....

Of the 2 conflicting activities, whichever is on top in the manifest file is the one that will work. So if activity from manifest #1 is on top, plugin #1 will work but not #2, and vice versa.

The two conflicting activities are:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.devfo.andutils.DevfoUnityPlayerActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

And:

```
<activity android:name="com.qualcomm.QCARUnityPlayer.QCARPlayerProxyActivity" 
android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

is there any way I can merge the two and get them to work from the same app? I'm using Unity 3d.

Comment: you should know which activity you want to use as entry point, shouldn't you ?

Comment: using Unity I don't normally work directly with activities....I didn't write the activities I bought them as a plugin...they work independently but not when combined....

Comment: Did you end up figuring this out? I'm stumped.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle: How to merge Android manifest files for different buildTypes which need the same Activity, but with different intent-filters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18708076/gradle-how-to-merge-android-manifest-files-for-different-buildtypes-which-need)

Answer (score 6):

For example in the manifest where you want to use only the first activity as launcher you have to add this 2 modifications:

At the beginning of the manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
```

And for the activity for which you want to remove the intent filter add this code:

```
<activity android:name="com.qualcomm.QCARUnityPlayer.QCARPlayerProxyActivity" 
android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen">
  <intent-filter tools:node="removeAll">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

The important part is to add the **tools:node="removeAll"** attribute in the intent-filter tag

Comment: I think you can shorten it just to <intent-filter tools:node="removeAll" />

Answer (score 2):

Declare your manifest header like this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
```

And then add one of the following appropriate attributes to the relevant Activity(s):

```
tools:merge="override"
tools:merge="remove"
```

Answer (score 2):

Slightly different to @amarkovits answer, I've found success with:

```
<activity android:name="com.qualcomm.QCARUnityPlayer.QCARPlayerProxyActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait"
          android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen"
          tools:node="merge">
            <intent-filter tools:node="remove"> ...
```

which I believe will try to merge it first, then replaces just the intent filter causing both Icons on the launcher screen

Answer (score 1):

The `Activity` that has this `intent-filter`:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
```

is the main `Activity` that will start on application start up, you can't make both activities work at the same time.

what you should do is let only one Activity ( your main one have this filter) and leave the other one without it.

the second `Activity` will also be part of the application, but it will not be the first `Activity` you will see. You can start it by using the `startActivity()` method.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this, the solution is that when you have multiple flavors, like 
1. flavorA, 
2. flavorB 
and main application id is - com.android.vivek

and main flavorA is using com.android.vivek
and second flavorB is using com.android.vivek.flavorb

flavorA's manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.android.vivek">

<application xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/flavorA_ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:replace="android:icon" />

    <activity
        android:name=".ActivitySplash"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        tools:node="replace">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

 </application>
```

then simply flavorB's manifest mention like below

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.android.vivek">

<application xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/flavorB_ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:replace="android:icon" />

    <activity
        android:name=".flavorB.SecondActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        tools:node="replace">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".ActivitySplash"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">

        <intent-filter tools:node="remove">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

 </application>
```

when you run flavorA or flavorB then it will work fine