# How to use a different launcher activity in a product flavor?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, android-productflavors

I'm working on an Android library project, in the default src/main/AndroidManifest.xml, the MainActivity is the launcher activity.

For the sake of something else, I created product flavors.  Yes, it works perfect if I want to trigger / show different activitis inside different product flavors.  However, I wanna keep the **default launcher activity** from **src/main/** folder, while register another flavored activity as the new launcher activity.  So that for different product flavors, I could have different launcher activities, and from them I could still start original "launcher" activity in src/main/.

Could anyone kindly tell me how to achive that?  Thanks a lot.

Notes:

1. Adding `if (BuildConfig.FLAVOR.equals("flavorName"))` code to original launcher activity is not prefered.  Because I don't want to modify the production code from someone else (this is a library project).
2. I've tried `manifestmerger` and `tools:replace`, but seems like it doesn't work for `intent-filter` (I noticed that the element merging policy for intent-filter is always).

`<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />`

If this may work, could you please kindly guide me how to make it work?  Thanks.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

What I have tried:

1. Enabling **Manifest Merger**, which doesn't work;
2. Using **activity-alias**, which doesn't work either.

Finally I found out that the problem could be solved by just adding one line:

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

==================================================

To make it clear, I'll go through the problem and solution one more time:

Under `src/main/java` there is a `MainActivity`, and in corresponding `src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` it specifies MainActivity as the launcher activity:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

That is a very easy part.  Now we start with the product flavor part.

Due to some reason, in a product flavor, I don't want to overwrite the MainActivity, instead, I have a `YetAnotherMainActivity`.  The goal is to **set the `YetAnotherMainActivity` as the new launcher activity in the product flavor, and it should still be able to call `MainActivity`**.

And here, is how you can set the new activity in product flavor as the new launcher activity:

`flavorX/AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<activity android:name="com.example.YetAnotherMainActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_yet_another_main_activity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Yep, it turns out deadly easy.  Just add `android.intent.category.DEFAULT`.

Comment: Thanks @AdamFręśko, maybe it's not the best solution, but so far it's working :)

Comment: This installs two apk for when I run the app on the device

Comment: @IsmailIqbal it seems like unfortunately yes

Comment: I followed another examples,  https://stackoverflow.com/a/34183747/4944007

Comment: Thanks @IsmailIqbal but as I said above in one comment, "`tools:node="remove"` will remove that original launcher activity which I would like to keep".  Where I mentioned in my original question that, "I wanna keep the default launcher activity".

Answer (score 10):

I think that `<activity-alias>` fits there more than any other solution (have no idea why @JingLi couldn't get it working. Maybe there were some troubles year ago, but for now it's okay).

For example, we have the following manifest in `main`:

```xml
<manifest
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.application">
    <application>
        <activity android:name=".InfoActivity"/>
        <activity-alias 
            android:name="com.example.application.Launcher"
            android:targetActivity=".InfoActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity-alias>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

And we want to replace launcher activity with `DebugInfoActivity` from `debug` flavor. So, we need to just replace the `targetActivity` attribute in the specified `<activity-alias>` tag:

```xml
<manifest 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <application>
        <activity android:name=".DebugInfoActivity"/>
        <!-- to not litter the manifest -->
        <activity 
                android:name="com.example.application.InfoActivity"
                tools:node="remove"/>
        <activity-alias
                android:name="com.example.application.Launcher"
                android:targetActivity=".DebugInfoActivity"
                tools:replace="android:targetActivity"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Notes:

- In the example we use the same package name for `main` and `debug`.
- We have to enter the full name for activity-alias, so the merger can merge their correctly.

With the solution we also can inherit all attributes and childs from `main` activity-alias to not duplicate their in `debug`.

Comment: I haven't tried if `<activity-alias>` works or not now (after one year as you said).  But my question is about "using a different launcher activity, without removing the original launcher activity".  That's why I prefer simply adding `<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />`.  And your code here `tools:node="remove"` will remove that original launcher activity which I would like to keep.  Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Ouch. Don't know how I missed that. So, especially if you want to preserve your `intent-filter` for `MainActivity`, maybe your variant fits there good too.

Comment: This works, except I would do `tools:node="replace"` instead of `tools:node="remove"` so you can still keep your **InfoActivity** and just change which acts as launcher. For me @JingLi alternative created two different launchers (as is I had the app installed twice)

Comment: This works. Saved the day!!

Answer (score 2):

I guess I am not late :)
So today I got the same problem. @seroperson solution was correct but If you do not want the default launcher activity at all then just use the below code in your flavor's manifest:

```
<activity
        android:name=".DefaultLauncherActivity"
        tools:node="remove"
        >
```

Comment: My question is about "using a different launcher activity, without removing the original launcher activity".  And your code here `tools:node="remove"` will remove that original launcher activity which I would like to keep.

Comment: This works for the general case of removing a default merged item in a build variant.

Answer (score 0):

Android merger is merging *intent-filter* from main manifest lancher to flavors. I have not found way to prevent that. You end up with 2 app icons on device (each for launcher Activity).

Based on that, you cannot override completely settings from main manifest. Solition may be to keep only shell of manifest in main folder and implement manifest in each flavor or to remove conflict Activities from main folder and implemenent independently in each flavor.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.adamassistant.app">

    <!-- empty shell, implementation in flavors folders -->

</manifest>
```

Answer (score -1):

The simplest and cleanest solution is to keep only one Manifest and write two different MainActivity.java class one for each flavor in order to avoiding duplication of manifest nodes.

Given two flavors in gradle

```
productFlavors {
        paid {
            packageName "com.example"
        }

        demo {
            packageName "com.example.demo"
        }
    }
```

Given this project structure

```
app/
|--libs/
|--src/
   |--paid/
   |  |--java/
   |     |--com/example/
   |        |--MainActivity.java
   |--demo/
   |  |--java/
   |     |--com/example/
   |        |--MainActivity.java
   |--main/
      |--java/
      |  |--...
      |--res/
      |  |--...
      |--AndroidManifest.xml
```

And this Android Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.flavors">

    <application
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Thanks but sorry, you should read my question carefully.  I mentioned "I wanna keep the default launcher activity, but have another new activity as the new launcher activity".  So your solution doesn't work for me, since it's replacing the other MainActivity.

Answer (score -1):

Create a different AndroidManifest.xml file in your flavor. And there set your DifferentFlavorMainActivity.java as the launcher activity with full name like:

```
android:name="com.android.application.paid.MainActivity"
```

Answer (score -3):

The working simplest solution is to use manifest merging and using

```
<intent-filter tools:node="removeAll">
```

as suggested in the following post :

[Merging android manifest files, conflicting filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19795582/merging-android-manifest-files-conflicting-filter)